# How to open an app by clicking on different extension attached in gmail?

Tags: java, android

I have two different extension file (.PTI, .PDB), which is attached in the gmail. I wanted this attached file to open with my specific app. Below is my code what i am trying..

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*.PTI" >
                    <data android:host="*" />
                </data>
            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*.PDB" >
                    <data android:host="*" />
                </data>
            </intent-filter>
```

This is working for only .PTI file. But when i am trying to open .PDB file with the same app, it is saying "No app found to open this file". How can i do this for both .PTI as well as .PDB?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<intent-filter>` for PDB has `<data android:scheme="conten" />` - missing a 't'. It should be

```
<data android:scheme="content" />
```